# Failed to build pyarrow for streamlit installation

Tags: python, streamlit, pyarrow

I am trying the command pip3 install streamlit on a virtual environment on my raspberry pi 4, but I got the following error. Could you help me, please?

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build pyarrow

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [447 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/json.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/compute.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/cuda.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/pandas_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow
      copying pyarrow/feather.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/pyarrow

[...................]

- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/tmp/pip-install-91b26ump/pyarrow_a18751cde5d44d1b9b7fce68cb5127b5/build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      error: command '/usr/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to explicity install pyarrow

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.fury.io/arrow-nightlies --prefer-binary --pre pyarrow
```

and then try to install streamlit
Note: This works for python version 3.11

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have Python 3.9.2 version. I tried your command but I was not able to explicitly install pyarrow.

Comment: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple, https://pypi.fury.io/arrow-nightlies
Collecting pyarrow
  Using cached pyarrow-12.0.0.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pyarrow) (1.24.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [288 lines of output]